# Disconnected Citrix Users

Tags: windows-server-2003, citrix

We have a problem where a couple of users keep getting disconnected from their Citrix sessions and we cant understand why it only affects a few users where other users going through the same Web Interface to the same Citrix server don't get suddenly disconnected. It doesn't log them off either, when they go back into the Citrix, all the work is still there, so it just disconnects them.  Anybody come across this before or can point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

**Additional Info:**
It's *Citrix 4.5 XenApp* running on *Windows 2003 R2 SP2*

Comment: By 'don't understand', do you mean their network connection is a local wired connection that is very stable?  Also, most organizations setup their servers so that sessions are not be logged off immediately when disconnected, due to it may result in data loss (or job loss).

Comment: @GregAskew "...sessions are not be logged off immediately when disconnected, due to it may result in data loss (or job loss)."  That actually makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Id probably start with the simplest things...

- network errors, check managed switch interfaces for errors if possible.
- maybe its terminal issues, switch a user to a different terminal that doesn't exhibit the issue?
- on the citrix web server look at windows event viewer, there should be a citrix specific log that could indicate whats going on with these disconnects

Comment: Done all of that.  And an interesting part there is no error in the event viewer...

Answer (score 0):

OK if the server isn't seeing errors, then you need to check 'upstream' in your network topology.  The problem you've presented is very specific - Citrix is dropping the connection on the user end, but the terminal server is perfectly happy to keep the session going in case they should reconnect.

- What do the affected users have in common other than Citrix dropping their connections?
- Are they all connected off the same physical switch/router, or on the same subnet?
- Are they on WAN connections running thru the same WAN router, or using the same PIX VPN access point?
- Do they share a common broadband provider, one that may be a bit ill-behaved when it comes to terminal sessions or VPN tunnels?
- Are they all on dialup?

This is a networking / connectivity issue, isolated to these particular users.  I'd recommend chasing it from that direction rather at the server.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said look at potential network issues first and look for anything these particular users have in common (same location, same network connection (same switch etc))

Are there any events recorded on their workstations that indicate a connection (or other issue?)

Try carrying out a network capture using your preferred tool (Netmon, wireshark etc) from the workstations having an issue and see what happens during the disconnection. Also do a capture from the server end to get the full picture.

Eliminate AD/Group membership as an issue

Do they have (or don't have) the same group membership as working users?

Eliminate the workstation as an issue

- Is there anything different about the workstations/devices they use
  (same Citrix client as working users.)
- Does the issue follow them to another machine?
- If a 'working' user tries from a non-working user do they then get
  the issue?

Answer (score -3):

There is one more big flaw in the Citrix.. If we go to Task Manager and check for users logged in. Then all the users who are logged into the same domain are visible. Also any one in these users can log out any other user by right clicking on that user details and disconnecting or logging off his session..

At times we need to check that someone in the organization isn't playing fail with others. If there is a way to find a log details to identify such misdeeds performed by other client users. They may be doing this for fun sake but still they are not authorized to do it. Do not give them the access to that window under Task Manager, if we can avoid it.

I don't know how helpful this information is technically. I personally experienced such misdeeds in my previous organization (I don't want to name it.).

Comment: Hi, not only does this not answer the question, but this 'flaw' is part of Windows Server, not Citrix. Finally, it's purely a case of appropriate permissions and configuration.